# Multi Macro Communication

Tags: vba, date, excel, formatting

I am currently attempting to self-teach myself the great world of macro coding in VBA but have come across a stumbling block when trying to process 3 macros that I would ideally like to process as 1 but the code seems to be far too complicated for me at this stage.

What I need is to convert data from US date format mm/dd/yyyy into UK date format dd.mm.yyyy and changing the / to . at the same time ideally overwriting the original data.

This is currently what I have in separate Modules:

```
Sub FixFormat()

'display a message with an option if US date formats are
'included in the data
 MsgBox "US Date Formats Included", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Addresses"
If Response = Yes Then MsgBox "Delimit Process Needed", vbOKOnly, "Addresses"
If Response = No Then MsgBox "End", vbOKOnly
End

End Sub
```

and

```
    Sub FixDates()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If InStr(cell.Value, ".") <> 0 Then
        cell.Value = RegexReplace(cell.Value, _
        "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})", "$3.$2.$1")
    End If
    If InStr(cell.Value, "/") <> 0 Then
        cell.Value = RegexReplace(cell.Value, _
        "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})", "$3.$1.$2")
    End If
    cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-d;@"

Next

    End Sub

Function RegexReplace(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal replace_what As String, _
                      ByVal replace_with As String) As String

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = replace_what
RE.Global = True
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(text, replace_with)

End Function
```

Is there any way to do this without having to run 2 separate macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can `Call` the subroutine you want to run as a result of the message box.

```
Sub FixFormat()

'display a message with an option if US date formats are
'included in the data
If MsgBox("US Date Formats Included", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Addresses") = 6 Then
    MsgBox "Delimit Process Needed", vbOKOnly, "Addresses"
    Call FixDates
Else
    MsgBox "End", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

See this link for more information on the MsgBox function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx